# wxWidgets splitted windows

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create structure to draw many graphs in separate sub windows one below another, something that looks like that :[image]

I need to change the size of these graph by dragging lines separating them.

I tried using panes in wxAUI but resizing one affects other, and it seems to be rather unstable. The main problem is that when I'm moving one sash to another it starts pushing it. Maybe there is some way to solve it?

I also tried using multiple `wxSplitterWindow` each nested in another, but this strategy also seems to fail because resizing one window affects all nested inside and their splitters are moving due to sizing even if I try to cach event `EVT_SPLITTER_SASH_POS_CHANGED`.

Do you have any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Both solutions (AUI and `wxSplitterWindow`) should work, which one of them is best depends on what exactly do you want to do. You should describe your goal (i.e. how exactly should the panes resize when the separator is dragged) as well as the problems you encountered more precisely.

Comment: HI. My problem is, that, in AUI, one sash is pushing other sashes and resizing all other graphs. Also `wxSplitterWindow` is affecting all other windows nested inside. 
The effect i want to achieve, is that when moving one line between graphs it only affects the size of two graphs that this line divide. Including some minimum size of the graph. 

I recently tried using `wxBoxSizer` and `wxFlexGridSizer`, still no effects

Comment: @VZ. I just found what I need, but unfortunatelly it is only for wxPython. It is called MultiSplitterWindow.

Comment: Is it important to use subwindows here? I wonder if you could add your own draggable elements between the graphs, and resize each graph based on where the draggable is dropped.

Comment: @halfer thanks, I guess it is good idea, i just need to put graphs inside some window or frame. Still it will require creating quite complex class, because whole thing must have dynamic number or graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is indeed no out of the box solution doing what you need. `wxSplitterWindow` itself is implemented using wxWidgets API, so you could adapt its code to create your own window supporting multiple splitters, AFAICS it should be quite straightforward but, still, will require some work.

Comment: I thought of modyfing `wxSplitterWindow` code to create what I want, but i guess it will require a lot of time, as I am quite new to wxWidgets